# Get the required fields for Google Tag Manager

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am currently integrating a google tag manager in one of my Silverstripe websites and I require to programatially retrieve details of Product name, order total price and currency. I have retrieved the other details like order id, coupon code but I am unable to retrieve the Product name, order total price and currency. Kindly guide me on how to retrieve the mentioned details.Here is an example on how I retrieved the coupon code.

```
$coupon = $order->Modifiers('Discount')->first()->CCode;
```

Comment: SilverStripe doesn't ship with products or order models out of the box - you must be either using your own code for this or a third party module. Can you please provide more information, such as which module you're using for this?

Comment: Thanks Robbie. I figured out the solution. I will be using jQuery or this.